# Unable to find symbol when building using maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have forked the following repo:
[flameSDK](https://github.com/nidongara/FlamesSDK-Java). I've made a minor change, just adding a log to it but when I try and create the jar via maven install, the build seems to fail. Getting a `cannot find symbol.` I even tried `mvn clean install` before I made any changes but still the build fails due to that error.

The error stems from something regarding generated files. I am using the above repo as a maven dependency in my other project and it works fine with no error but I would like to make a minor change and then use my modified version of the sdk in my app.

Not sure why it fails, I was assuming since it works, the build should pass just fine.. any suggestions?

Comment: But the message occurs despite any changes made to the repo. As soon as I fork it and try to build it, it fails because of that message but it's weird because I'm using this repo as a maven dependency on my other app and it works fine..

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the project. You should probably contact the maintainer. I checked an earlier commit and got further in the compilation step, but generating documentation failed instead.

Comment: I'd stand by the first (now retracted) duplication flag and would recommend to 1) check the JDK you're using to compile (make sure it's the same that the maintainer uses) and 2) make sure you're not compiling a commit that doesn't compile in the first place - e.g. take a tagged/released build that you change. Then 3) Check your "minor change" for typos - read right-to-left, then it's easier to find typos in your own code. Or post it here. (and maybe start with 3.) `mvn clean install` naturally can only reveal the same if the underlying code has a compile-issue.

Comment: I just did `git checkout 02a4f5b` and at that point it built ok.